# Why is wx.SingleChoiceDialog not subclassing properly

Tags: python, oop, wxpython, subclass

I'm trying to subclass the wxpython SingleChoiceDialog class.  I have a TableChoiceDialog class that inherits from SingleChoiceDialog adding generic functionality, and I have 2 sub classes for that add more refined functionality.  Basically I'm O.O.P'ing

In my TableChoiceDialog class I have a line which calls the superclass's `__init__`, i.e.

```
class TableChoiceDialog(wx.SingleChoiceDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, message, caption, list, ...other args...):
        wx.SingleChoiceDialog.__init__(self, parent, message, caption, list)
```

The problem I'm having is that according to the `SingleChoiceDialog.__init__` docstring (and the wxPython API), SingleChoiceDialog does not have the self argument as part of it's `__init__` method.

```
    __init__(Window parent, String message, String caption,
        List choices=EmptyList, long style=CHOICEDLG_STYLE,
        Point pos=DefaultPosition) -> SingleChoiceDialog
```

As I have it above, the program prints the error:

```
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'wxSingleChoiceDialog *', no destructor found.
```

If I take out the self parameter the system complains that it was expecting a `SingleChoiceDialog` object as a first argument, which seems to point to it actually wanting a reference to self.

When I take out the parent argument, leaving self (and the other 3 which I'm pretty sure are fine) the system complains that it only recieved 3 arguments, when it needed 4.  I'm pretty certain I'm passing 4.

So.  What blatantly obvious mistake have I made?  Have I totally misunderstood how python handles objects (and hence pretty much misunderstood python)?  Have I misunderstood OOP as a whole?

Please help.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. The call to `__init__` seems alright (the first argument to `__init__` is always `self`).
2. You might have a wrong build of `wx`. The swig's warning message indicates that there is no desctructor was generated for `wxSingleChoiceDialog`, see [this memory leak discussion](http://lists.osafoundation.org/pipermail/pyicu-dev/2006-March/000040.html).

The message may be unrelated to the `__init__` call.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the dialogs in wxPython are not subclassable because they are not real classes, but instead wrappers around the platform API method for displaying the dialog. I know this is the case for `wx.MessageDialog`, it might also be the case for `wx.SingleChoiceDialog`.